# Some returns true when false is expected

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to validate if all person in the array pass the validation.
Why this gives me true and how can I properly validate ALL elements?

```js
const people = [{
  name: 'Johnysadafsasffsa',
  age: 20
}, {
  name: 'Johny',
  age: 60
}]

isValid = people.some((e) => {
  return e.name && e.name.length === 5 && e.age > 50
});

console.log(isValid);
```

PS: I want all elements to have age over 50 and name length of 5

Comment: It seems correct - the second element in the array has a name with five characters and age over 50. So, some of the elements pass the predicate. EDIT: wait, are you just looking for `.every()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you swapped two array methods: some and every

```js
const people = [{
  name: 'Johnysadafsasffsa',
  age: 20
}, {
  name: 'Johny',
  age: 60
}]

isValid = people.some((e) => {
  return e.name && e.name.length === 5 && e.age > 50
});

console.log(isValid);

isNotValid = people.every((e) => {
  return e.name && e.name.length === 5 && e.age > 50
});

console.log(isNotValid);
```